# How can I access Microsoft Graph's isOnlineMeeting property?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft graph event library in C# but intelisense does not list the property isOnlineMeeting as shown on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0

Using the graph explorer I can see that isOnlineMeeting is in the response but not through the Microsoft.Graph.Event library in C#

How would I go about accessing this property?

Here is how I am trying to access the event information:

```
private static Booking GetBookingInfo(Event ev)
{
    var Id = ev.Id,
    var Start = Booking.ParseDateTime(ev.Start.DateTime),
    var Meeting = ev.IsOnlineMeeting;
```

Comment: I think we need more details please provide more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have provided a code example

Comment: WHat error do you see>?

Comment: Event does not contain a definition for IsOnlineMeeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this library: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet?

If yes, what version are you using?

`IsOnlineMeeting` is a newer property [added to MS Graph API in April 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog#april-2020). That means that you might need to update the library to a newer version. For me, `IsOnlineMeeting` property is available in the newest version (3.6.0).

Comment: Thank you. I updated the Microsoft.Graph package via NuGet in Visual Studio and all is now working.